# laravel storage embed pdf not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-filesystem

I want to embed a PDF file into a modal blade view. The disk is not public (because it shouldn't be) and with a logged in user, I get the `404 not found` message.

Inside **config/filesystems.php** I got:

```php
<?php
    'disks' => [
        'custom' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/custom'),
        ],
```

Inside my **blade view** I already tested successfully

`<iframe src="https://www.inkwelleditorial.com/pdfSample.pdf" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>`

However, when I try:

`<iframe src="{{ storage_path('app/custom/myFile.pdf')}}" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>`

I get

> 404 NOT FOUND

I have made sure the file does exist:

`dd(Storage::disk('custom')->path('myFile.pdf'))` => shows absolute path correctly

`dd(Storage::disk('custom')->exists('myFile.pdf'))` => returns true.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First,you must know that `storage_path()` is a private path.
if you want show storage file on web, you can see the config file `config/filesystems.php`

```php
    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],
```

run this command: `php artisan storage:link` , then go to `public` directory,you can see the soft link directory on the `public` directory.

Then you can  use the url on webpage like this `<ifram src="/storage/app/custom/xxx.pdf" ></iframe>`